# Application of Cauchy-Schwarz on integrals

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is of the following form:
\begin{align}
\bigg|\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}G_\epsilon(x,y)f(y)dy\bigg|^2\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}G_\epsilon(x,y)dy\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}G_\epsilon(x,y)f(y)^2dy,
\end{align}
where $G_\epsilon(x,y)=p_\epsilon(x-y)-p_\epsilon(x+y)$ with $p_\epsilon(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}}\exp\{-\frac{z^2}{2\epsilon}\}$.

This is not the original form of Cauchy-Schwarz, obviously. I just don't get how to arrive at the above inequation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $x \in \mathbb R^{+}$ observe that $G_{\epsilon} \geq 0$. Define $\mu (E)=\frac {\int_E G_{\epsilon} (x,y) dy} {\int_{\mathbb R^{+}} G_{\epsilon} (x,y)dy} $. then $\mu $ is a probablity measure and hence $|\int f(y)d\mu(y)| \leq \int |f(y)|^{2} d\mu (y)$.

Comment: The nominator is equal to 1, so one might define the measure by $\mu(E)=\int_E G_\epsilon(x,y)dy$ and we can say that $G_\epsilon$ is its density, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.